# VBA Macros Creating a new Table from a selected Row, controlling first the color of another cell above

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in the subject VBA Macros, I'm trying to generate a new table with the formation of another, the information will be used with two conditions:

1. if the information in the cell is active(marc) in the row have been chosen as a mark in the picture No 1

   [image: Chosed(active, mark) Row and Titles]
2. if the cell color in the title is green, in row 6

   so after check those 2 points, it takes the information of the 2 cells and put it in a new table and keeps doing this till the last cell with a green background in line 6.

   In the second picture is the end product
   [image: End product]

This is what I have tray till now:

```
Sub SelectColoredCells()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim rColored As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rColumn As Range
    lColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Set rColored = Nothing
    Set rRow = Range("$6:$6")

    For Each rCell In ActiveCell.Row
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lColor Then
                For Each rColumn In Selection
                   If rColumn.Value <> "" Then
                       MsgBox rColumn.Address
                     If rColumn.Value = "" Then
                            Exit For
                        If Sheet1.Cells(6, rColumn).Interior.Color = lColor Then
                         Sheet3.Cells(rRow, rColumn).Value = 
                         Sheet1.Cells(aRow,rColumn).Value
                        End If
                      End If
                    End If
                Next
            If rColored Is Nothing Then
                Set rColored = rCell
            Else
                Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
        MsgBox "Selected cells match the color:" & _
            vbCrLf & rColored.Address
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rColored = Nothing
End Sub
```

So how can I make it to look up into the cell with the title of the active row?

Comment: So what is your actual question? Because this is no free code writing service, please [edit] your question and show the code you already have tried and ask a question related to it (you didn't even ask a question yet). Reading [ask] might help to improve your question.

Comment: Oh Sorry, You are right thanks! I will upload the code now.

Comment: PEH thanks for the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to unify all colored headers into a range `MarkedHeaders` and then use `Offset()` to move to the currently selected row.

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectColoredCellsAndCopy()
    Dim SelectedRow As Long
    SelectedRow = Selection.Row 'remember seleted row

    Const HeaderRow As Long = 6 'define row that contains headers

    Dim LastHeaderColumn As Long
    LastHeaderColumn = Cells(HeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get last used column in header

    Dim MarkedHeaders As Range

    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To LastHeaderColumn 'run from 1 column to last column in header row
        If Cells(HeaderRow, iCol).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
            'check color and unify all colored cells into MarkedHeaders
            If MarkedHeaders Is Nothing Then
                Set MarkedHeaders = Cells(HeaderRow, iCol)
            Else
                Set MarkedHeaders = Union(MarkedHeaders, Cells(HeaderRow, iCol))
            End If
        End If
    Next iCol

    'now all colored headers are unified in MarkedHeaders
    'and we can move this selection to the previously selected row

    Dim SelectedRowColoredTitles As Range
    Set SelectedRowColoredTitles = MarkedHeaders.Offset(RowOffset:=SelectedRow - HeaderRow)
    'use offset to move 'selection' from the headers to the previosly selected row

    SelectedRowColoredTitles.Select 'just to show whats inside SelectedRowColoredTitles now
End Sub
```

You can then use

```
MarkedHeaders.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(HeaderRow, 1) 'copy headers
SelectedRowColoredTitles.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(SelectedRow, 1) 'copy row
```

to copy the headers or selected row into another sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for PEH. I will not have made it without your help I'm 2new in the subject. seriously thank you!!! I really have to learn much more

Comment: I will. PEH Can I writhe you again if I step into a problem in the future? thx again

Comment: @Mocty You can just open up a new question, no matter if the question is a follow up or totally new question. Just add your code and give a good description of your issue, tell your error messages or where you got stuck. Anyone will answer you then.